# How to use a .NET Automapper's ValueResolver ? (Updating from v3 to v6 of Automapper)

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm updating an old project that it using Automapper v`3.3.1` upto the (currently latest) v`6.2.2`.

I have a custom resolver which now doesn't compile. I'm not sure how to refactor it, to work with the newer versions of `ValueResolver`.

#### Current Code

```
CreateMap<TwitterShareJsonModel, Tweet>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Content, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ShareContentResolver>());

...

public class ShareContentResolver : IValueResolver<SharingJsonModelBase, ShareContent>
{
    protected override ShareContent ResolveCore(SharingJsonModelBase source)
    {
        if (source.Post == null &&
            source.Profile == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Must have a Post or Profile shared.");
        }

        return source.Post != null
            ? (ShareContent) Map<SharingPostJsonModel, SharePost>(source.Post)
            : Map<SharingProfileJsonModel, ShareProfile>(source.Profile);
    }
}
```

I've noticed that I need to change the inheritance to an `IValueResolver` (which now requires three input types).

Answer (score 0):

From the AutoMapper documentation, IValueResolver has the following definition,

```
public interface IValueResolver<in TSource, in TDestination, TDestMember>
{
    TDestMember Resolve(TSource source, TDestination destination, TDestMember destMember, ResolutionContext context);
}
```

If we consider the following,

```
public class Source
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

CustomResolver to Map the Total field to sum of Value1 and Value2,

```
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<Source, Destination, int>
{
    public int Resolve(Source source, Destination destination, int member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.Value1 + source.Value2;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
   cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Total, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var source = new Source
    {
        Value1 = 5,
        Value2 = 7
    };

var result = Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source);

result.Total.ShouldEqual(12);
```